# How to find clicked UIElement child

Tags: wpf, uielement

I would like to get the clicked UIElement's child element that is button. Maybe there is simple and short solution for this? I have searched for this answer awhile, but could't find solution that would be easy to understand and use. I will appreciate any kind of help related to this question.
Code that i have right now:

```
private new void MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    if (sender == (sender as UIElement))
    {

        //TODO: getting controls name that is placed inside clicked UIElement

    }

}
```

Edit:
Wanted to mention that UIElement is ContentControl that is using ResourceDictionary template.
My xaml code looks something like this

```
 <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource DesignerItemStyle}">
        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="add function" IsHitTestVisible="True" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: it depends on what UIElement you mean here, such as if that UIElement is the owner of the event `MouseLeftButtonDown` which is attached with the handler, you can use either `sender` or `e.Source`, otherwise you may have to look into `e.OriginalSource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two properties in `MouseButtonEventArgs` which you can leverage for this purpose

**`Source`**

This property contains reference to the object that raised the event. example Button etc

**`OriginalSource`**

the original reporting source as determined by pure hit testing, before any possible `Source` adjustment by a parent class, which may have been done to flatten composited element trees. example a Rectangle, Border or any template element inside the Button.

you can retrieve the `Name` for the element by `casting` `OriginalSource` to `FrameworkElement` or more appropriate

if the `OriginalSource` is not the desired element then you can retrieve the Logical parent of `OriginalSource` and that is more likely to be the desired element and retrieving Name remain same as above.

retrieve logical parent example

```
LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @pushpraj . I changed this line of code that you gave to something like this and it worked! - `var childControl = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(e.Source as DependencyObject);` Then to get that child controls name just used foreach loop. Great!

Comment: I just realized that this method only returns that child element's Content not name or other properties. Also when i cast to FrameworkElement that e.OriginalSource also no way to get other properties than Content.

Comment: You can define a strategy to cast to `Panel` to get its children or a `ContentControl` to get It's content depending on the type of object or other suitable types as needed. `FrameworkElement` is quite basic example which helps to get `Name` property. You may post a working sample of your app. May I suggest after looking at it.